# Has DBAN completed wiping when it's showing an advertisement?

Tags: hard-drive, wipe, dban

I ran DBAN (Darik's Boot And Nuke) on my notebook. When it finished, it showed a message saying "press any key to continue". When I pressed a key, I got an advertisement page, and then it stopped.

Has my hard disk been wiped completely?

Comment: The advert was added when the rights to dban were [purchased by Blancco](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dban/forums/forum/208932/topic/5998582).  There were [no other changes](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dban/forums/forum/208932/topic/6136616).

Comment: @ColinPickard Thanks!!. I'd like to ask u something. If I run 8 pass and then I run 1 pass again.  My harddisk has security as 1 pass?(because it's last). I'm afraid 8 pass that i ran before is wasteful.

Comment: If you think its wasteful run it less thats entirely your choice.

Comment: @Ramhound First I ran it 8 pass.when it finished,I get an advertisement page and then it stops. 
I think it's ploblem,so I run it again with 1 pass.
I'm afraid security that I ran 8 pass is lost

Comment: @Napat Maipaiboon - If you ran it 8 times then ran it 1 times, you ran it, 9 times in total.  You do understand what the application does right?

Comment: @Ramhound I'm sorry.I think "wasteful" same meaning "lost".

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks for your answer!.I'm too stress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's wiped completely. I don't remember that it had an advertisement. Since the last time I used it, maybe they changed something because it's free.

Comment: Thanks. I would like to ask something.If I run dban 8 pass,can I run it again??.

Comment: U boot it from a usb drive or? If its still avaible on the drive then u can run it again. If i answered ur question, mark my answer as answer please :)

Answer (score 6):

The accepted answer is correct.

However, to throw some more light on the problem, I remark that
DBAN was purchased by Blancco in 2010, which is when the ad was added.

An examination of the [SourceForge DBAN page](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dban/files/dban/) shows that the ad was added in
version 2.2.6 and also that some useful development was done at that time
of beginning 2012.

As no development was done since beginning 2012, it might be worthwhile to look for
an alternative product.

DBAN itself is criticized in the article
[Securely Erase A Hard Drive – DBAN May Not Be Sufficient](http://techlogon.com/2012/07/07/securely-erase-a-hard-drive-dban-may-not-be-sufficient/)
as not actually wiping the entire disk.

You could have a look at the article
[Best Free Hard Drive Eraser](http://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-hard-drive-eraser.htm), where the winner is [Eraser](http://eraser.heidi.ie/),
but other products are also recommended
(it's also advisable to read the comments).

I remark that
the dwipe program that DBAN uses has been forked and is available as a standalone program called Nwipe,
included with partedmagic (if you want a bootable CD version).

Comment: nwipe also ships with both _large_ and _small_ variants of the [GRML](http://grml.org/) livecd. ([package list](http://grml.org/files/grml64-full_2018.12/dpkg.list))